# Change date format FacetWP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, post-meta, facetwp

If I filter on date range in FacetWP plugin for Wordpress. I outputs the URL like 2018-11-29 but I want it to output the date without '-'. So it is gonna be 20181129. Does someone know how to achieve this?

Comment: You mean this? https://facetwp.com/documentation/date-range/

Comment: Yes, YYYY-MM-DD  needs to be YYYYMMDD

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the documentation, you can customize the front-facing date with `Formatting tokens`: https://facetwp.com/help-center/facets/facet-types/date-range/#tokens.

> d – day (2 digits)
> j – day (without leading zeros)
> m – month number (2 digits)
> n – month number (without leading zeros)
> F – month (full)
> M – month (short)
> y – year (last 2 digits)
> Y – year (full)

Using this sintax, to achieve your desired result, with `Facet 4.2.8`, you should change the `Display format` field to "Ymd" in the settings (see the image below).

[image: FacetWP Settings Panel]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35419717)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I tried to improve my answer.